# Strange Challenge UIScrollView inside tableview (each section) with dynamic height

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Thanks for helping me through whenever I stuck.

This is a different challenge altogether, I want to display section headers similar to the one used by tableview's and I will have to use scrollviews in each of the section.

I have around 4-5 sections, but these sections contents and themselves are dynamic, if there is no data then they wont be displayed, if there is any data then a section is displayed with its corresponding data, but I have a scrollview for each of the sections(1row in 1 section) whose contentSize is dynamic based upon the content (in my case these are dynamic images of different height).

so what's the best way to update the section row with a new height or what's the best way to update a row cell with the new height and corresponding update the contentsize of the table I believe.

Many Thanks,

Reno Jones

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {return calculatedHeight:}
```

Use this UITableView delegate method to pass the height of the section header.

But you need to reload the tableview to make this function gets called.

Best Regards.

Comment: No brother, this is not the right solution, had it been that easy then I would have done it long ago. Content of scrollviews are not text, instead they are images whose rect is not with me, they get added dynamically into the scrollview. :) Thanks though.. :)

Comment: I hope that you could find the height of the section header height while setting the contentSize of the scrollview. As soon you find that you could reload the tableview and pass the contentSize.height as the height of that particular section.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to override couple methods of `uitableview`

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

in the viewForHeader method, you can create a separate .nib file, get it as the view and config the data properly to return as the header. and calculate the height of course

and of course

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

again, create a separate .nib file as your cell view, you can simple drag & drop an scroll view in to it. And you'll have to calculate the height considering the data you want to show in the cell

Comment: Brother everything is cool, but I dont have the data with me prior to creation of cells (section), I have got images to display in different sections (scrollviews) and everything is of dynamic in size.

Comment: I don't think I understand what u are saying. You have to provide the data source before show the table. If data source is changed afterward, you'll needs to call reload on table.  Dynamic data means you have to calculate and properly position your controls in cell, such as hide one or whatever.  The cell .xib file should provide as a template. If a row data is complete and normal, then the template is good. If not, then you need to hide, move up or scale controls in the template based on the row data